# Javascript string prototype method split

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have created a function named “show_alphabet” and assign to a variable named “str”, a string of the letters of the alphabet in uppercase. 
I have used the prototype property of the String object to add a method named “sendArray” and assign this (sendArray) a function which returns the split() method. The split() method will split the alphabet string.
I also have a variable named “arr” and I have assigned it the sendArray() method for “str”.
I have a button that when clicked will run the show_alphabet function.
The function is supposed to display  the alphabet letters in the “str” as an array with period colon followed by each letter and placing each letter on a separate line. 
For example:

A:

B:

C:
…

However, whenever I click on the button, nothing is displayed.

Here is my code:

```
<form>
  <button type = "submit" value = "submit" onclick = "show_alphabet()">submit </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_alphabet() {
    var str = new String("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    String.prototype.sendArray() = function() {
      return this.split("");
    }
    for (i=0; i<str.length-1; i++) {
      var arr = str.sendArray(":" + "<br />");
      document.write(arr[i]);
    }
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: You are calling `sendArray()` before defining the function. `for` loop appears incomplete? Where is `arr` defined?

Comment: 1. remove `String.prototype.sendArray()` brackets here. 2, `sendArray` doesnt take any parameters

Comment: @TheReason Love your name.

Comment: 1) When calling `sendArray()` you are adding a parameter, but there is no parameter for the prototype function sendArray() and 2) it should be `String.prototype.sendArray =` without parentheses

Comment: `String.prototype.sendArray() = function() {` should be `String.prototype.sendArray = function() {`

Comment: You have put the button in a form. By default it's a submit button, so it's submitting the form and reloading the page so even if the function runs, you won't see the result. Get rid of the form or make the button `type="button"`.

Comment: Homework.  But any which way... you have so many issues: sendArray should not be defined with parens, sendArray takes no parameters, you can't actually document.write after DOM load like this, and sendArray is 100% extraneous and unnecessary any which way (since you can just address the string by index).  So, downvote.

Comment: The string.prototype.sendArray is required in case any of you are wondering.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't stand these horrible answers, so I felt compelled to offer a correct one.

```
<button type="button" value="submit" onclick="show_alphabet()">submit</button>

<div id="dynamic"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_alphabet() {
    var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    document.querySelector('#dynamic').innerHtml = str.split('').join(':<br/>');
  } 
</script>
```

To recap some of the issues:

- You can't document.write after the DOM has loaded.  Doing so will generally only cause you frustration.  Instead, as above, tweak the innerHtml or use a dozen other ways to change the DOM.
- Set the button as type="button" instead of type="submit".  Doing so will preclude either an actual form, or an implied one, from executing.
- Your sendArray function didn't make any sense... but neither did most of the answers.  Just make the string and set it somewhere, and iteration just isn't necessary here.

Comment: Pretty good answer. Just one nitpick - by using `String.join()`, there will be no `:<br/>` after `Z`

Comment: You can use *document.write* after the page is loaded, however a consequence is that it replaces the entire content of the page.

Comment: @RobG - Sure.  But have you ever ran into a situation where document.write on a loaded DOM was actually useful for something?  I remember thinking it was neat in 1995 when Netscape 2 came out.

Comment: The point is that it *can* be done, not whether it's sensible to do so as a general strategy.

Comment: @RobG - That's certainly true... and I'm fine if we diverge in our opinion of what a 'good' answer is.  The usefulness of code is high in my paradigms, but I can understand if 'it works' is good enough for others.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I didn't expect to see so many incomplete answers. So let's summarize

1. The definition of the sendArray prototype function must not have parentheses
2. Above all, you don't need any sendArray prototype function (unless it is explicitly required by the Homework exercise)
3. You are passing a parameter to sendArray which you don't use inside the function
4. The action `submit` on the button will submit the form and hence refresh the page, so you won't see any other results of your code
5. You'll have to understand that pushing the button will use document.write, which will (after DOM loaded) always erase the previous document, including your script

Try it like this

```
<button type="button" onclick="show_alphabet()">Show alphabet</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_alphabet() {
    var str = new String("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    var arr = str.split("");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = arr.join(":<br/>");
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank heavens for that. Why do the simplest questions get the worst answers?

Comment: @RobG - Honestly, this answer is no better IMO.  It will still never work because of the document.write.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It has been ages since I used document.write so I actually forgot how useless it really was :-)

Comment: @JohnGreen—it "works" in that it writes the alphabet to the page, and there's a note that it will delete the entire content of the page first, so bases covered.

Comment: @RobG - Yes, those stipulations were added in the edited version, which was made after my answer and comments.

Answer (score -3):

`sendArray = function()` instead of sendArray() = function()

Comment: This is only less than half an answer

Comment: Yup, but he should start with that. Sorry I didn't see your comment